# Angular Js : Simple app not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning AngularJS from codeSchool and I was making a simple hello world app , initially it was being rendered properly but after some time It didn't work at all. I am not able to detect the bug , please help
Here is the code for html  file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="store">
<head>
    <title>Angular Code School</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    I am {{4+6}}
    {{"Hello +"World"}}
<div ng-controller="StoreCtrl as store">
<div ng-repeat="product in store.products| orderBy:'-price'">
<h2>Name :{{product.name}} </h2>

    <h2>Price:{{product.price | currency}} </h2>
    <h2>Description:{{product.description}} </h2>
    <button ng-show="product.canPurchase">Add To Cart </button>

<section ng-controller="PanelCtrl as panel">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li ng-class="{'active':panel.isSelectedTab(1)}"><a href ng-click="panel.selectTab(1)"> Description</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{'active':panel.isSelectedTab(2)}"><a href ng-click="panel.selectTab(2)">Specs</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{'active':panel.isSelectedTab(3)}"><a href ng-click="panel.selectTab(3)">Reviews</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-show="panel.isSelectedTab(1)">This is description div</div>
    <div ng-show="panel.isSelectedTab(2)">This is Specification Section</div>
    <div ng-show="panel.isSelectedTab(3)">This is Reviews section</div>
</section>
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

appTest.js

```
var app = angular.module('store', []);

app.controller('StoreCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    this.products = gems;
}])

gems = [{
    name: 'Dodecahedron',
    price: 2.95,
    description: 'This is the description of Dodecahedron'
    canPurchase: false;
},
{
    name:'Diamond',
    price: 5.95,
    description: 'Diamond is the most luxuriest gem of all.'
    canPurchase:true;
}]

app.controller('PanelCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    this.tab=1;
    this.selectTab = function(setTab) {
        this.tab = setTab;
    };
    this.isSelectedTab = function(checkTab){
        return this.tab===checkTab;
    }

}])
```

The structure of my directory is like

```
root/
   angular.js
   appTest.js
   index.html
```

Here is the page with console
[image]

Comment: is there any error on the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

appTest.js

```
var app = angular.module('store', []);

app.controller('StoreCtrl', function() {
    this.products = gems;
});

app.controller('PanelCtrl', function() {
    this.tab = 1;

    this.selectTab = function(setTab) {
        this.tab = setTab;
    };

    this.isSelected = function(checkTab) {
        return this.tab === checkTab;
    };
});

var gems = 
    [{
        name: 'Dodecahedron',
        price: 2.95,
        description: 'This is the description of Dodecahedron',
        canPurchase: false
    },
    {
        name: 'Diamond',
        price: 5.95,
        description: 'Diamond is the most luxuriest gem of all.',
        canPurchase: false
    }];
```

and in index.html
`{{"Hello" +"World"}}` should be `{{"Hello" + "World"}}`

Answer (score 0):

You're messing a double quote:

```
{{"Hello +"World"}}
```

should be:

```
{{"Hello " + "World"}}
```

Check your console for javascript error.

Answer (score 0):

Three issues:

- Modify the hello words as below

  {{ "Hello" + "World"}}

in your appTest.js,

- add the comma after description fields of the 'gem'
- remove the ";" semicolon after "canPurchase"

in your html file

- ensure you are including "appTest.js" and not just "app.js"